# readfile in directory outside of public_html

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to read a file outside of the `public_html` folder.

```
$file = '/var/www/new.txt';

$fileHandle = file_get_contents($file);
if($result)
{

    $o = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    
    if ($o)
        readfile($file);
    else
        echo 'Error authenticating please contact support';
}
else {
    echo '';
}
```

I think the php file doesn't have permissions to access this file, how would I be able to make it have access to this file?

Comment: ... file_get_contents does *not* return a file handle. also $result is *undefined* in your code.

Comment: @hanshenrik $result is a variable declared outside of the code that i sent above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to access your file via relational path.

for example your folder structure is:

```
-folder
   --new.txt
 
-public_html
   --reader.php
```

in your reader.php :

```
<?php
    $file = '../folder/new.txt';
    
    $fileHandle = file_get_contents($file);
```